# Sending post request using apache jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am using following code to send requests to sparql endpoint. These requests are GET requests. When i send queries i get following error :    414 Request-URI Too Large. I found out that i can solve the issue by sending post requests. Need to know how i can send post request.

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(this.endPoint, query);
ResultSet resultSet = qexec.execSelect();
```

I am using the following query :

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/> 
SELECT ?entityName ?categoryName
WHERE { VALUES ?uri {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Roger_Federer> } 
      {?uri  (dcterms:subject|rdf:type) ?category .  
      OPTIONAL {?category rdfs:label ?categoryName . 
                ?uri rdfs:label ?entityName. } 
      } 
      FILTER(lang(?entityName) = 'en' && lang(?categoryName) = 'en') 
      FILTER (?category = dbpedia-owl:TennisPlayer || 
              ?category = yago:TennisOrganisations || 
              ?category =<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:The_Championships,_Wimbledon>
             )
     }
```

Here in the values for uri, these are populated by the system on the fly, and they are large in number which increases the length of the query.

Comment: Can we see the query you are using?

Comment: What system are you sending the query to?

Comment: @AndyS : Sending query to virtuoso sparql endpoint

Comment: @AnthonyHughes : added the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `HttpQuery.urlLimit`, though the default is 2K bytes which is usually fine. (current version).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution to problem. I used QueryEngineHttp to send http post query and it worked.

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
QueryEngineHTTP qeh = new QueryEngineHTTP(this.endPoint, query);
ResultSet resultSet = qeh.execSelect();
```

Comment: That is what your original code was effectively doing.  Did you set  `HttpQuery.urlLimit` as well?